# Can't set a blacklist for usb autosuspending

Tags: linux, usb, suspend, laptop-mode

I'm trying to disable usb autosuspend for my wireless USB mouse:

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND="auto"
AUTOSUSPEND_USE_WHITELIST=0
AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKIST="046d:c52f"
```

I already put these values to `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf`, and restarted `laptop-mode`, but that just don't work (it still stuck for one second when I move my mouse)

Answer (score 1):

After adding my mouse ID to the blacklist, I had to unplug the mouse and plug it back in again for the blacklist to work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem because of an mistake in the usb_autosuspend config file. The correct config is something like:

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
AUTOSUSPEND_USE_WHITELIST=0
AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST="046d:c52f"
AUTOSUSPEND_USBTYPE_BLACKLIST=""
AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_WHITELIST=""
AUTOSUSPEND_USBTYPE_WHITELIST=""
BATT_SUSPEND_USB=1
LM_AC_SUSPEND_USB=0
NOLM_AC_SUSPEND_USB=0
AUTOSUSPEND_TIMEOUT=1
```